# Hexadecimal dividing $\frac{17a}{12}$ with remainder

Tags: arithmetic

How much is it $\frac{17a}{12}$ (in hexadecimal)
I got $15$ with remainder $a$.
Can someone confirm its true?

Thank you!

Comment: 15 is correct but there is no remainder.

Comment: If you're using Windows, then: open the Start menu, write 'calc' and press Enter to launch the calculator, open the View menu, choose Programmer, choose Hex and enter $17A/12$.

Comment: @cr001 quick question, if it would be 18a/12, is my answer correct?

Comment: I should note that different countries do long division differently. (It's the same algorithm, but the numbers are sometimes arranged differently.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's false.

Since the claim is equivalent to $$17A_{16}=12_{16}\cdot15_{16}+A$$

One can confirm as the following way:

$$17A_{16}=16^2+7\cdot16+10=378$$

While

$$15_{16}\cdot12_{16}+A=(16+5)(16+2)+10=388\neq378$$

Obviously, by observation, we have

$$15_{16}\cdot12_{16}+A=17A_{16}+A$$
$$15_{16}\cdot12_{16}=17A_{16}$$

So it should be:

$$\frac{17A_{16}}{12_{16}}=15_{16}$$

Answer (score 2):

Just like in the case of the division algorithm in the base then system, first you take a look at $$17a:12$$

and you realize that $17/12=1$ and the remainder is $5$.
So you have after the first step
$$
\begin{matrix}
17a&:12&=&1\\
\color{white}{|}5
\end{matrix}
$$
then you "bring down" the next digit of the dividend:
$$
\begin{matrix}
17a&:12&=&1\\
\color{white}{|}\color{blue}{5a}
\end{matrix}
$$

then you guess the result of the division $\color{blue}{5a}:12$. My first guess is $5$. Indeed $12\times5=5a$.

You right this down the following way

$$
\begin{matrix}
17a&:12&=&1\color{red}5\\
\color{white}{|}\color{blue}{5a}\\
\ \color{red}{ 5a}
\end{matrix}
$$

now, you subtract $\color{red}{5a}$ from $\color{blue}{5a}$. The result would be the remainder, zero this time, because there is no more numbers in the divident to be brought down.

Answer (score 0):

Just do long division...

```
12 / 17A \ 15
     12
     --
      5A
      5A
      --
       0
```